# Using @ and $ with the same variable name in Perl

Tags: perl

I am declaring the same variable name with `@` and `$`:

```
@ask=(1..9);
$ask="insanity";
print ("Array @ask\n");
print ("Scalar $ask\n");
```

Without using `use strict` I am getting output correctly but when I am using `use strict` it gives me a compilation error.

Do these two variables refer to two different memory locations or is it the same variable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You've got two variables:

```
@ask
$ask
```

You could have `%ask` (a hash) too if you wanted.  Then you'd write:

```
print $ask, $ask[0], $ask{0};
```

to reference the scalar, the array and the hash.

Generally, you should avoid this treatment, but the variables are all quite distinct and Perl won't be confused.

The only reason `use strict;` is complaining is because you don't prefix your variables with `my`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ask = (1..9);
my $ask = "insanity";
my %ask = ( 0 => 'infinity', infinity => 0 );
print "Array @ask\n";
print "Scalar $ask\n";
print "Hash $ask{0}\n";
```

Comment: "You could have %ask (a hash) too if you wanted."

also '&ask' ;)

Comment: @MySZ: yes, you're correct; also `*ask`, which you might use indirectly with: `open ask, '>', $ask or die; print ask @ask;` — an old-style file handle, in other words.  That gets warnings about 'bare words' ("Unquoted string "ask" may clash with future reserved word"), though. You used to use `local(*ask);` in a function to create (roughly) the equivalent of a lexical file handle, but lexical file handles are so much cleaner.  I just didn't want to complicate things too much.

Answer (score 15):

with `use strict;` you need to declare your variables first before using it.

For example:

```
use strict;
my @ask=(1..9);
my $ask="insanity";
print ("Array @ask\n");
print ("Scalar $ask\n");
```

Comment: @mpapec I absolutly dont understand ; maybe it is the game  ... I already received downvote for good answer by the past ...

Answer (score 1):

`@ask` and `$ask` are different variables — as is `%ask` — and it is not an error to do this. It is however poor style.

Because the sigil changes when you use them, such as when you use `$ask[1]` to get the second element of `@ask`, the code becomes harder to read and `use strict` will also not be able to tell if you've gotten confused. Thus it's a good idea to use names that differ in more than the sigil unless you know what you're doing. So you could use e.g. `@asks` and `$ask`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting with [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) is not due to variable names. It is because you are not declaring the variables (using one of [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html), [our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html), [local](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html), or [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html). Nor are you using the [vars](http://perldoc.perl.org/vars.html) pragma.

Short answer: Stick a `my` in front of each variable, and you'll be `strict`-compliant.

For package variables, you can examine entries in the [symbol table](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables). `$ask` and `@ask` are separate entities:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Devel::Symdump;
use YAML;

@ask=(1..9);
$ask="insanity";

my $st = Devel::Symdump->new('main');

print Dump [ $st->$_ ] for qw(
    scalars
    arrays
);
```

Among other things, this code will output:

```
--
…
- main::ask
…
---
…
- main::ask
…
```

Being able to use the same name can help when, say, you have an array of fish and you are doing something with each fish in the array:

```
for my $fish (@fish) {
   go($fish);
}
```

Normally, it is more expressive to use the plural form for arrays and hashes, the singular form for elements of an array, and something based on the singular form for keys in a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @ships = ('Titanic', 'Costa Concordia');
my %ships = (
    'Titanic' => {
        maiden_voyage => '10 April 1912',
        capacity => 3_327,
    },
    'Costa Concordia' => {
        maiden_voyage => '14 July 2006',
        capacity => 4_880,
    },
);

for my $ship (@ships) {
    print "$ship\n";
}

while (my ($ship_name, $ship_details) = each %ships) {
    print "$ship_name capacity: $ship_details->{capacity}\n";
}
```